# how can i store data in local and get data from that when inter ne is not present?

Tags: iphone, caching

i have one application , in this application what is i want to store all data in local.so i can run application when inter net is not present.like caching .

My application is not local its online application .just i want to store all page in cache . so i can get page when internet is not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you want like this.

Suppose data is coming from json parsor or xml parson whatever.

Means you have data. so you can create one file with cache extenention and store all that data in it. whenever next you open that page if internet is not present that time just get data from that file.

what you say its correct or not ?

Comment: hey thank you. i think i got the perfect ans. this is the think i want .

Answer (score 0):

If the application will be accessed through a standards-compliant browser, you can use [HTML5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).